# How to ignore shift(1) error in first line of df when using .cumsum() in python

Tags: python

I have a data frame (df) which I am using the `.cumsum()` to keep track of current watermark status. According to an "if" condition I update it (the column is named Accum_tbid) with `df.tbid.cumsum()` or keeping the last one (if the criteria doesn't matched) with `df.tbid.cumsum().shift(1)`

this is line of code:

```
df['Accum_tbid'] = np.where(((df['tradePrice'] <= df['bid1']) &\
                             (df['isTrade']==1)), 
                             df.tbid.cumsum(), 
                             df.tbid.cumsum().shift(1))
```

The problem I face is how to ignore the shift(1) when it's the first line of the df (as I will get a Nan)

Comment: I hate to say, but the best way to ignore something is just to ignore it. Does having a NaN in the first cell cause any problem down the line? If not, do nothing. If it does, explain what is the problem.

Comment: Well, yes it does. Later I am grouping and doing more calculation based on this data and it fails as I can not calculate NaN....

Comment: Since this is a NaN that you _intentionally_ produced, there must be an _application-specific_ way to handle it. You may discard the whole row, or replace NaN with a 0, or replace it with the mean value of the row/column. Only you would know what is the right solution.